# Count 1 in Binary,difference between 0 and NULL

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

The question is Count how many 1 in binary representation of a 32-bit integer. I wrote in C++.

First I have the code

```
int countOnes(int num) {
    int count=0;
    while(num>0){
        count++;
        num=num&num-1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

but it didn't pass with the information

### Input -1(11111111111111111111111111111111) Output 0 Expected 32

When I change the code into this

```
    int countOnes(int num) {
    int count=0;
    while(num){ //difference here
        count++;
        num=num&num-1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

it is accepted.
So, what is the problem? can somebody help me?

Comment: Oh come on. You expect `num > 0` to be true when `num == -1`?

Comment: Think about it: you gave it -1 and your condition says "while it's larger than zero"

Comment: Ok,I got it,thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

As other suggested, unsigned vs. signed might be tripping you up here.

I did this, using a template argument so you can use different types of numbers:

```
template<typename Num>
unsigned int count_binary_1(const Num& number)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    unsigned int count = sizeof(number) * 8;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if ((number >> i) & 1)
        {
            ++result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: nice but `& 1` not required

Comment: Heh, I'm just paranoid.  Removed it to make the code a tad cleaner (after testing).

Comment: Ah, so it is.  I didn't check my results on the edit carefully enough.

Comment: Are you using sizeof to determine the width of the passed integer?

Comment: Yes... sizeof should give me how many bytes are required for the type of 'Num' used.